# Do we have methods prescribed in Rig veda to prevent natural calamities?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

Does Rig Veda talk about natural calamities and its implications on Earth?

If so, does it also talk of how such calamities can be prevented or controlled?

Request answer only from Rig veda.